# Is BGP required for VPN peering with gateway transit in Azure

Tags: azure-virtual-network

If I have a setup of 2 peered VNETs (`Vnet1` and `Vnet2`).`Vnet1` has s2s VPN running to `on-prem`. `Vnet1` peering has "Use this virtual network's gateway or Route Server", `Vnet2` peering has "Use the remote virtual network's gateway or Route server" enabled. Site2Site VPN does not have BGP enabled. Is this configuration will automatically allow VMs placed on `Vnet2` to route to devices in `on-prem`? Does it require BGP enabled or custom routes added on subnets in `Vnet2`?

Answer (score 0):

Not required, but if you want this to work phase2 of S2S VPN would need to have your `Vnet2` IP addresses added and tunnel needs to be bounced.